# no puedo tener getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

```
`
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;`
```

trato de que al hacer click en un item de una lista que esta en un fragmnet me lleve a otro fragment[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir los imports y la declaración de `DiezFrut`? Una captura de pantalla en este caso no es ideal para encontrar el error.

Comment: Ya tienes el import correcto, ahora Realiza un Build > Clean Project @Sergio

Comment: aun no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes importar `Fragment` y `FragmentManager` de `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` y `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` respectivamente (NO de `android.app.Fragment` y `android.app.FragmentManager`).

ejemplo:

```
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

...
...
...

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

---

Si aseguras tener lo anterior entonces el problema es el contexto, el contexto que usarías seria el de la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, en este caso debe ser:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: aun no funciona

Comment: extiende de fragment

Comment: Sergio, revisa mi actualización! FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() el problema en realidad es el contexto ,  en este caso tomaremos el de la Activity que contiene el Fragment.

Comment: Gracias, are otra pregunta, espero me puedas en esa tambien

Comment: @Sergio Que bien, claro con gusto. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: ya la publique.