# Error al ejecutar AsyncTask en DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, método, asincronismo

Este es mi código el cual uso originalmente, en este código intento ejecutar un método asíncrono en un DatePickerDialog

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment //Se modifica a metodo estatico
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT , this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
        year = y;
        month = m;
        day = d;

        globalVariable.calendar.set(year, m, day);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        fechaSelected = sdf.format(globalVariable.calendar.getTime());

        new getEventsAyncTask().execute(); //método que no es estático 
    }
}
```

El problema es que se necesita que el método sea estático para ejecutarlo dentro del pickerdialog alguna idea de como hacer para ejecutarlo sin tener que cambiar el método asíncrono a estático?

Comment: Hola Alexis, puedes explicar qué error te da? Un saludo

Comment: hola que tal, al poner el puntero sobre getActivity que es en donde se marca todo rojo el mensaje dice cannot resolve symbol 'getActivity'

Comment: Acaba de añadir una captura de pantalla para que se vea mejor el problema muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: lo que contiene la captura no es más que el codigo que ya tenias. No añade nada nuevo a la pregunta. Yo la quitaría y pondria el error que pusiste en los comentarios en formato de texto. Lee [ask]

Comment: Acabo de poner el error que se genera al debuggear

Comment: Si mostraras el codigo de la clase donde esta el metodo `obtenerFragments()` seria mejor y no lo hagas con una imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es ocasionado por que no existe la variable getActivity, probablemente lo que estas buscando, es ejecutar la funcion getActivity().

Comment: exactamente, necesitaría hacer algo mas en ese método para poder hacer uso de esa función?

Comment: @AlexisCaballero la funcion esta dentro de un Activity o un fragment?

Comment: originalmente estaba en un método onPostExecute como se puede ver aquí [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/error-en-m%C3%A9todo-as%C3%ADncrono-est%C3%A1tico] pero me recomendaron hacerlo afuera

Comment: Y por que no utilizas las instancias de los fragments para ejecutar las funciones de refresh()?

Comment: El caso es de que el método asíncrono es estático porque lo estoy ejecutando en un DatepickerDialog y este tiene que ser estático y para que el método asíncrono funcione tiene que ser estático

Comment: No tiene nada que ser estático, algo esta mal con tu código, si estas obligado a hacer las funciones estáticas es que no estas haciendo las cosas bien. En un DatePickerDialog puedes ejecutar funciones no estáticas.

Comment: Es que estuve informandome sobre esa cuestión, y encontré que en métodos estáticos no se pueden ejecutar métodos no estáticos, tendrían que se los dos métodos estáticos para poder interactuar

Comment: @AlexisCaballero los metodos de instancia si pueden ejecutar metodos estaticos. Es al revez que no se puede.

Comment: es que anteriormente ya había hecho eso de instanciar y ejecutar el método asíncrono en el DatepickerDialog pero me marcaba el error de que no se podía ejecutar un método no estático entonces lo que hice fue optar por hacer que el método asíncrono fuera estático para evitar ese pero a raíz de esto surgieron esos problemas

Comment: Algo me dice que intentaste ejecutar la funcion estatica dentro de un evento en el pickerdialog, fue asi?

Comment: si exactamente, ahorita regrese el código a como lo tenia en un principio, en ese código el único error que se me registraba era que no podía ejecutar el método asíncrono dentro del pickerdialog porque este no era estático y el pickerdialog si

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error:

> Error:(373, 27) error: cannot find symbol variable getActivity

indica que la variable `getActivity` no existe. En realidad lo que se necesita es el método [**getActivity()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

Si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment`, usa como contexto el `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, mediante [**getActivity()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()):

Recuerda que `getSupportFragmentManager()` es un método de la Activity:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44603/95

Este sería tu código:

```
 for (Fragment f : getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
 ...
 ...
```

---

Si es que desearas usar la variable `getActivity`  (lo cual no es común) puedes realizar esto, obteniendo el contexto y almacenandolo en la variable `getActivity` :

```
 Context getActivity = getActivity(); 

     for (Fragment f : getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar este metodo

Comment: hola @AlexisCaballero , en realidad es  el método que debes usar, agregué también si es que deseas usar la variable, no cual no veo necesario.